# How can I specify a type for a function argument without restricting its dimensions?

Tags: arrays, types, julia, multiple-dispatch

In Julia, I want to specify the type of a function argument as an array of arrays. So I have

```
function foo{T <: Any}(x::Array{Array{T}})
```

but if I set the argument `x` in the REPL, for example:

```
x = Array[[0,1],[1,2,3],[0,1,2,4]]
```

then it automatically gets the following type assignment (for example), which includes its dimensions:

```
x::Array{Array{T,N},1}
```

so that I get the error

```
ERROR: `foo` has no method matching foo(::Array{Array{T,N},1}).
```

I don't want to restrict the array dimensions at all, so was thinking that the solution maybe something along the lines of

```
function foo{T <: Any, N <: Number}(x::Array{Array{T,N},N})
```

but this doesn't work either.

How can I specify the argument type to be an array of arrays?

Comment: Could you include an example of how to generate something like your `x`? My hunch is that you're running into [invariance](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/types/?highlight=invariant#parametric-composite-types), and that a definition like `foo{T<:Array}(x::Array{T})` will do the trick.

Comment: Yep that works, I wasn't sure about the rules for putting the ```{T<:Array}``` bit in. For example if I had more than one argument with the same issue, how can I put in multiple type parameters? Thanks for the link, it was very helpful, I wasn't sure where to look before. I have added an example of how I generate ```x``` to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given an array of arrays `x = Array[isodd(i) ? [1i,2i] : [1.0i 2.0i] for i=1:10]`, Julia reports its type as `Array{Array{T,N},1}`.  This is deceiving, as it seems to imply that there exists some `T` and some `N` for which the above type will match.  But that's not the case: the odd elements will be of type `Array{Int,1}`, and the evens are `Array{Float64,2}`.  So when you try to write a method for `foo` with the type parameters:

```
foo{T,N}(::Array{Array{T,N},1}) = T,N
```

What are `T` and `N` for `x`?  Clearly, there is no such N — it's *both* 1 and 2!  And the elements of these subarrays aren't of type `Any` — they're *both* `Int` and `Float64`.  The same applies for `Array[[0,1],[0,1,2]]`, even though in your example you know that `T` and `N` are consistent, Julia's type system doesn't… and you could potentially push elements that aren't Int vectors.

There are quite a few ways around this.  The best approach is to try to make sure that your arrays always have concrete (or at least uniform) element types, but that's not always possible.  Given your example `x` above, you could instead write: `x = Array{Int,1}[[0,1],[1,2,3],[0,1,2,4]]`.

Another alternative is to change your function signature:

```
foo{N}(x::Array{Array,N}) = 1 # Will *only* work for arrays like x above
foo{T<:Array, N}(x::Array{T,N} = 2 # Will work for all arrays of arrays
```

The first will only apply if you have exactly that type due to [invariance](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/types/?highlight=invariant#parametric-composite-types), whereas the second will work for all Arrays of Arrays, both poorly-typed and concrete.

(Edit: As a final note, `N<:Number` won't match literal numbers. It will match *types* that are a subtype of `Number`, like `Real` or `Int`.  There's currently no way to express that a type parameter must be a *value* of type `Int` beyond the convention that N is an integer).